# adding to an array based on condition php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Database table:

```
 Table Name: friends

   user_id   |  friend_id  |  accepted  |  key_id  
 --------------------------------------------------
    123      |    234      |     2      |    1     
    123      |    456      |     2      |    2
    123      |    789      |     1      |    3     
    222      |    123      |     2      |    4     
    498      |    123      |     2      |    5
```

Initial Query (To get confirmed friends)

```
$user_id=123;
$query="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE
    (user_id='$user_id' OR friend_id='$user_id')
    AND accepted='2'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   if($row['user_id']==$user_id)
   {
       $friend[]=$row['friend_id'];
   }
   if($row['friend_id']==$user_id)
   {
       $friend[]=$row['user_id'];
   }
}

print_r($friend);
```

What I am trying to do is set into the `friend` array the matching id's where either the user_id is equal to the `$user_id` or the friend_id is equal to `$user_id` and the accepted value is 2. At present the above is not returning anything and I am not sure whether I am formatting/creating the array correctly.

What would be the best way to achieve the correct results in this case. I also need to format the array so it can be included in another MYSQL statement using the `IN()` condition to select from another table.

Comment: That code literally as is won't work. Do you have a typo in the fetch call?

Comment: Thats me being in a rush :)

Comment: did your query return any results?

Comment: No - this is what is confusing me

Comment: why not re structure your SQL query instead in PHP

Comment: yes thats the best way.. your query should have results for the condition to run smoothly

Comment: you could use union like this: SELECT user_id 
FROM friends 
WHERE (user_id='$user_id' OR friend_id='$user_id') AND accepted='2'

UNION

SELECT friend_id 
FROM friends 
WHERE (user_id='$user_id' OR friend_id='$user_id') AND accepted='2'

Comment: Now this works just fine - but I can't get my head around why the original statement is not returning anything - I think I will stick to this. Thanks

Comment: BTW, as it stands, key_id seems to be redundant.

Comment: I'm just using it as a primary key - don;t really know if it is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this

```
$query="SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE (user_id = $user_id OR friend_id = $user_id)
        AND accepted = '2'";
```

Remember you should give integer not string. Its fetching records correctly.

Output

```
key_id  user_id friend_id   accepted
-------------------------------------
1       123     234         2
2       123     456         2
4       222     123         2
5       489     123         2
```

Comment: Thanks Raheel - I think you have just shown me the error of my ways - in my test database the id values are not integers yet I am treating them as integers. As the query is through an ajax request I am not getting the error message :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the needed parameter to `mysqli_fetch_array`:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)))
```

You can read more [in the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Sorry - should have cut and paste from my original code. I have edited the code.

Comment: Are you sure that `$row['user_id']` and `$row['friend_id']` contains something?